# give multitouch to view A, and A is behind to B View

Tags: android, android-view

I have two view A and B

A is MATCH_PARENET (width, height) and B is also MATCH_PARENT (width, height)

A view is covered by B View and B view is INVISIBLE

I have given Multitouch listener to A, but because of A is covered by B, I can not touch to A view because on top of A there is INVISIBLE, B view

Can any one help me how to do zoom-in out, rotate and move to view A

I have done by one way but it is not properly working

```
 multiTouchListener = new MultiTouchListener();

 a.setOnTouchListener(multiTouchListener);

 b.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                multiTouchListener.onTouch(a, event);
                return true;
            }
        });
```

I have given b's touch event to a,

but right now a is constantly moving if I simple drag my finger and stop

Comment: set clikable=false in B view parent layout

Comment: set visibility of view B to GONE .

Comment: no I need INVISIBLE, I can not make it GONE

Comment: @SiddhpuraAmit Then set clikable=false in the Top layout of view B , as Divyesh is suggesting .

Comment: @SiddhpuraAmit comment b.setOnTouchListener() and then try , along with this set clikable=false in the Top layout of view B ,  it should work .

Answer (score 0):

prevent B from getting touches, add these lines to the xml properties of B:

```
<View
   ...
   android:focusable="false",
   android:focusableInTouchMode="false",
   android:clickable="false" />
```

make sure you **do not** add any click/touch listeners in code to B, as it'll revert those properties.